# how to reduce feature dimensions

Tags: matlab, classification, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am seeking for help, I asked this question last week but no one answered me

I am using LBP with MATLAB for extraction feature but the accuracy is too low

how to reduce the feature bins in LBP?

many thanks.

Comment: Your question is too unclear and probably too broad. That's surely why no one answered.

Comment: Which library for LBP extraction you are using?

Comment: my problem is (the curse of dimensionality)

Comment: I am using matlab library

Comment: there is something called (Feature selection and Feature extraction) to solve the curse of dimensionality but I don't know how to use them in my code in matlab

Comment: Have you looked into PCA to reduce your dimensionality?

Comment: yes, i have, but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: @user3777182 - I have written an answer.  I'm surprised I didn't see this question until now.  I've written an answer on your other question too to ensure you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pcares`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pcares.html) function to do that.  `pcares` stands for **PCA Residuals**:

```
[residuals, reconstructed] = pcares(X, ndim);
```

`residuals` returns the residuals obtained by retaining `ndim` principal components of the `n-by-p` matrix `X`. `X` is the **data** matrix, or the matrix that contains your data.  Rows of `X` correspond to observations and columns are the variables. `ndim` is a scalar and must be less than or equal to `p`. `residuals` is a matrix of the same size as `X`.

`reconstructed` will have the reduced dimensional data based on the `ndim` input.  Note that `reconstructed` will still be in the original dimension as `X`.  As such, you can choose the first `ndim` columns and this will correspond to those features constructed using the number of the dimensions for the feature specified by `ndim`.  In other words:

```
reduced = reconstructed(:,1:ndim);
```

As such, `reduced` will contain your data that was dimension reduced down to `ndim` dimensions.

## Small Note

You need the Statistics Toolbox in order to run `pcares`.  If you don't, then this method won't work.